# Selenium 3.6.0, firefox 48, geckdriver 0.19 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: selenium-webdriver

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a
>   matching set of capabilities

Comment: Clearly mentioned that, `gecodriver 0.19` will support firefox browser 55 and above. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/release/CHANGES.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the release notes https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases gecko driver v 0.19 requires Firefox v55 and up. Please upgrade your browser and retry.

Answer (score 0):

It is compatibility issue of Firefox and Selenium Jars.

If are using jars 3.5.0 or above of Selenium then you need to use

- Firefox 55.0 (and greater)
- Geckodriver version v0.19.0

You can download latest [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) from these links

Also if you want to make it compatible then downgrade the geckodriver. it is better to use geckodriver 18 and selenium jar 3.5